# difference between dependency injection and autowiring

Tags: spring, autowired

1. Can I know what is the difference between dependency injection and autowiring? Whether autowiring is different from dependency injection?
2. Which is the best way to autowiring(XML based or annotation based)?

Comment: There is a third form to do auto-wiring, which is to neither use XML nor use annotations (although I'm unsure whether Spring supports this). Common practice is to define all a class's dependencies in its sole public constructor. When doing this, all metadata is available for the DI library to know what dependencies to inject and no extra annotations are needed. Almost all modern DI Containers for .NET work this way and modern one's don't even provide attributes to annotate your classes with. Spring might support this as well, and if it does, this should  be your preferred option.

Answer (score 27):

Short answer: Dependency Injection is a design pattern, and @autowired is a mechanism for implementing it.

The DI idea is that, instead of your object creating an object it needs (say by using new to instantiate it), this needed object - a dependency -  is handed to your object, typically using the constructor or a setter method. If you autowire, you're injecting a dependancy. In this case, Spring uses reflection to make this work, so you're not using the constructor or a setter method, but you're still injecting the dependency.

To answer question 2, its your choice. Personally, I find the XML configuration files cumbersome and use annotations whenever I can. You can accomplish whatever configuration you need to do either way.